# Transferring ownership to dead wallet?

Tags: solidity

Transfering the contract ownership to a dead wallet is the same of renouncing the contract? The contract doesn't have `renounceOwnership()`function on it.

Comment: Nice mopo you have

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, same thing. Although, if youre contract don't have a renounce ownership function, it's not using the standard https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol from OpenZeppelin, which is quite wierd. Has it been written by a dev on comission? If yes, you might wanna check for backdoors

Answer (score 2):

Yeah!
Technically, renounceOwnership means transfer contract's ownership to dead address so that the users can check the owner can not control the contract anymore.

What is important thing is we need to transfer ownership to dead address like `0x00...000` or `0x00...0dead`.
The contract can have `transferOwnership(address newOwner)` instead of  `renounceOwnership()`.
So you can call `transferOwnership(address deadAddress)` to renounce its ownership.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you. Yes contract has transfer ownership fuction, but no renounce.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally transferred my ownership on a token to dead address 0x0...001. Is it possible to take it back, and what are the pros and cons on this situation?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).